# Can I use a URL link to pre-select the value of a drop down menu?

Tags: url, forms, url-parameters

This is the webpage: http://dnr.alaska.gov/ssd/recoff/sag/BookandPageSearchMenu.cfm

I would like to be able to pre-select the District drop down menu using the URL that goes to that page.

Something like:

```
http://dnr.alaska.gov/ssd/recoff/sag/BookandPageSearchMenu.cfm?District=Palmer-311
```

But that doesn't work.

Is this possible using the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If the web page is set up with a script to parse the URL and set the select box accordingly, yes. It is not possible on a random page lacking such built-in capability (which is likely the vast majority of pages).